# Laravel skip results if they are found in previous query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm querying my DB twice to get some items into the header of the page and some bellow the header. I want to avoid duplicates in these two queries, currently I do this by adding a skip method to everything bellow the header. But I'm sure that I'm skipping some items altogether when doing this because I have 10 queries bellow the headernews and each of them are skipping 5 items while the header news are only taking the 5 newest items.

Is there a better way to avoid duplicates in these two queries?

```
$headerNews = News::orderBy('date','DESC')
->whereNotIn('portal', $notwantedTop3)
->take(10)
->get();

$bigSmallNews = News::orderBy('date','DESC')
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('news_category','Bignews')
    ->orWhere('news_category', 'Smallnews')
})
->skip(5)
```

Comment: Just take some news for header and then get small news by using whereNotIn the  second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$bigSmallNews = News::orderBy('date','DESC')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('news_category','Bignews')
            ->orWhere('news_category', 'Smallnews')
    })
    ->whereNotIn('id', $headerNews->pluck('id'))->get();
```